# How to install a laravel package from github

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php

I am sorry if this is a newbie question.

Basically,I want to install a laravel package(https://github.com/yovanoc/codetube/).

There is no documentation on how to install it.So i used this command:

```
composer create-project yavanoc/codetube --prefer-dist myproject
```

But  get this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find pacakage yavanoc/codetube  with stability stable
```

I can't use `git clone` because after that,I will not know how to go on further to complete the installation.It is only     `composer create-project yavanoc/codetube --prefer-dist myproject` command that I know can completely install a a laravel package and since that didn't work,I do not know what to do now.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you don't understand how laravel projects works. This is a repo that contains a whole Laravel project, so you need to clone it, there is no other way. It has all the files to serve a project. If you want to intsall to analyze how it works, clone to a separate project.

Comment: @Marco You're right.I don't understand how they work.Please tell me how to 'clone' it to install it

Comment: `git clone url-to-repo`.  You can't use this inside your own Laravel app, as it is an entire app, like Marco said, not a package.

Comment: @Devon So I should do `cd C:\xampp2\htdocs` Then `git clone https://github.com/yovanoc/codetube/` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off with using the `create-project` command. It would have worked if the package was on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/), the default Composer repository.

Since it's not on Packagist you need to do what the `create-project` command does yourself. Looking at the [documenation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) it says:  "This is the equivalent of doing a git clone/svn checkout followed by a `composer install` of the vendors." In your case you can do:

```
git clone https://github.com/yovanoc/codetube.git myproject
cd myproject
composer install
```